# ¿Cómo hacer un Scroll infinito con flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Quiero hacer una ventana de noticias, pero quiero que sea infinitas. Así como está solo se muestran 5, pero quiero que se cargue cada vez que llegas al fin de la pantalla.

```
import 'package:arsus/views/pages/home_page/new_card_component.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class NewsComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('content').orderBy("created_at").limitToLast(5).snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading...");
        }
        return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) => NewCardWidget(data: document.data())).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que ya lo tendrás resuelto, pero un paquete que te puede ayudar con esto es LazyLoadScrollView.

https://pub.dev/packages/lazy_load_scrollview

Es muy fácil de utilizar:

En el parámetro "onEndOfPage" defines la función que pedirá más información.

En el parámetro "endOfPageListener" controlas si tiene que buscar mas datos o ha llegado al final

En "child" añades tu lista y ya estaría. Te dejo un ejemplo de uso básico:

```
LazyLoadScrollView(
        onEndOfPage: () => loadMore(),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            return Text("Position $position");
          },
        ),
      ),
```